# How to Rename winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I've created a winforms application abc. I renamed it to xyz. when i try to run my application in my task manager it is showing abc.exe is running even i rename it to xyz.

How can i change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Project | Properties, select the Application tab, and enter the desired EXE name into the "Assembly name" field.

Comment: this was driving me crazy. But now in 2020, to rename the product name (the name what you see in desktop and unistall programs) you should go to: right-click on your project, go to Publish Tab, Then in Install Mode and Settings sections: click at Options... button. and finally set the name in Product Name textbox. This is it.

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this link, coming from ms itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3e92t91t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)